# How deterministic is Racket's evaluation order?

Tags: racket, evaluation

I would like to known how deterministic Racket's evaluation order is when `set!` is employed. More specifically,

1. Does `#%app` always evaluates its arguments from left to right?
2. If no, can the evaluation of different arguments be intertwined?

Take, for instance, this snippet:

```lisp
#lang racket

(define a 0)
(define (++a) (set! a (add1 a)) a)

(list (++a) (++a)) ; => ?
```

Could the last expression evaluate to something different than `'(1 2)`, such as `'(1 1)`, `'(2 2)` or `'(2 1)`?

I failed to find a definite answer on http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Scheme, Racket is guaranteed left to right. So for the example call:

```
(proc-expr arg-expr ...)
```

You can read the following in the [Guide](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/application.html): (emphasis mine)

> A function call is evaluated by first evaluating the proc-expr and all
>   arg-exprs **in order (left to right)**.

That means that this program:

```
(define a 0)
(define (++a) (set! a (add1 a)) a)

(list (++a) (++a)) 
; ==> (1 2)
```

And it is consistent. For Scheme `(2 1)` is an alternative solution. You can force order by using bindings and can ensure the same result like this:

```
(let ((a1 (++ a)))
  (list a1 (++ a)))
; ==> (1 2)
```